# How do I multiplex many asynchronous state machines over a fixed number of threads with boost::statechart?

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, boost

Suppose I have many asynchronous state machines defined with boost::statechart. The clearly documented mechanism for running multiple asynchronous state machines is to fix one or more of them to a thread. However, for my purpose I need to run many, many asynchronous state machines, and one per thread will not do. Moreover, the amount of work done by any given state machine is unpredictable, so assigning state machines to fixed threads will lead to imbalance.

Instead, I'd like to have a thread pool where an idle thread can pick up some amount of work off of a queue. Some care needs to be taken here so that events to a given state machine are delivered in order. Presumably the place to start would be something involving implementing the Scheduler and perhaps the FifoWorker concepts to do what I want as an alternative to the fifo_scheduler and fifo_worker classes, respectively. However, I wonder if this problem has already been solved by someone else, or if I'm just asking the wrong question.

Comment: This combination is currently out of my league due to insufficient experience with async statechart. But certainly look at Boost Asio.

Comment: Yeah, thread pools are nigh trivial with boost::asio, and I've figured out how to make sure events are delivered in order. However, I don't know how to mate that up with boost::statechart. If I can't get an answer here, I'll have to weigh trying to figure out how to implement the aforementioned concepts myself versus rolling my own state machine stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question, now that I've had some time to think about it. This is pretty simple:

- Every state machine gets its own fifo_scheduler
- When we want the state machine to start running, a function is posted to the thread pool that:

  1. Checks scheduler.terminated() and stops if so.
  2. Runs scheduler(*n*), where *n* is some implementation-dependent value. We need that to prevent starvation.
  3. Posts itself back to the thread pool.

This also ensures that events are delivered in order without resorting to other means.

This isn't the greatest answer, since the service function will occupy a space in the queue and be called even when there's no work to do.